# Convert octal value to letters and join together - JAVA

Tags: octal

I have a octal value, its - `0110 0145 0154 0154 0157 054 040 0110 0151`, the result must be - `Hello, Hi`.

Here is my code :

```
String octal = "0110 0145 0154 0154 0157 054 040 0110 0151 ";


    List<String> result = Arrays.asList(octal.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

    long item = 1;
    String res = "";

    while(item < result.size()) {
        char re = (char) Integer.parseInt(result.get((int) item), 8);
        res = res + " "+ re;
        item += 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Its" + res);
```

But the output :

```
Its e
```

Expected

```
Hello, Hi
```

I tried everything, but failed ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you think the split pattern `"\\s*,\\s*"` were a solution for your needs? To split at space, we can use `"\\s+"`.

And in order to start at the first letter, you should initialize `item = 0`.